# Docker run complains no such file or directory

Tags: docker, jenkins, aws-cli

**Scenario** 
Execute AWS-CLI docker container via Jenkin job to get status of EC2 instance, to be displayed on monitor

**Steps Taken**

1. Created Jenkins job
2. Executed AWS-CLI docker contair received response as a Json
3. Challenge is to parse received Json via jq or awk, <-- Failing in this step

**Execution Script**

```
`docker run --rm -v $VOLUME_AWS_CRED -v $VOLUME_FILE_STORAGE amazon/aws-cli  ec2 describe-instance-status --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --profile $AWS_PROFILE --include-all-instances --instance-ids  $INSTANCE_ID` > /root/aws/ec2_instancestatus.json
```

Written outcome above to ec2_instancestatus.json

```
`docker run --rm -v $VOLUME_FILE_STORAGE imega/jq '.InstanceStatuses[0].InstanceState.Name' /root/aws/ec2_instancestatus.json`

ERROR :: /tmp/jenkins6177799219393082837.sh: line 163: /root/aws/ec2_instancestatus.json: No such file or directory
```

**Stack Details:**

- Jenkin job executing on Docker Container on an agent node.
- Shell script bash style
- jq json parser

Comment: The error is not about `jq` here. Your JSON file seems to be unavailable for `jq` to run on

Comment: Why is there a stray character ` in your commands at last?

Comment: @Inian I have updated the stray character at beginning as well. That is the issue jq is not able to recogise this json file, however outside of jenkin worker node, this get accessible and available but not within container node.

Comment: Doesn't look like a jq problem.  Also the file mentioned in your output `/root/aws/ec2_status.json` is not the one in the command `/root/aws/ec2_instancestatus.json` ?  Perhaps replacing the `jq` command with something simpler like `cat` or `wc` might help you diagnose the issue.  I predict commands such as those will have the same problem reading the file.